# Specifying inline widths in css

Tags: css

Suppose you have this html:

```
<span> aaa </span> <a> bbb </a>
<br>
<span> ccccccc </span> <a> dddd </a>
```

You need the span to be of a certain width, so there is a certain layout.

How do you do this without resorting to floating divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could style the spans to be `display: block`, or `inline-block` (IE sometimes has issues with this) and then define the width.

Why? Well, span is a inline elmenent, and you cannot define width and height on inline elements, so you must "convert" the span to a block element.

Answer (score 1):

`inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to create a table without a table check this example of [definition list](http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/dl-tags-vs-table/)

Comment: Nice! I did not know that. is that compatible cross browsers?